# Create the [pentaho-report-designer] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-creation-request

A search for "Pentaho Report Designer" yields 294 results, and most of those results would be properly categorized under a PRD tag.

As it currently stands, people are attempting to concatenate the [pentaho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho) and [report-designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/report-designer) tag (the latter of which is supposed to be specifically referencing Microsoft Visual Studio questions):

[Pentaho Report Designer can't find MongoDB 's collections while connecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814059/pentaho-report-designer-cant-find-my-mong-db-s-collections-when-i-am-going-to)

Utilize Pentaho tags that in no way relate to their question (in this example, the [pentaho-cde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-cde) tag, which references a Pentaho dashboard product):

[Use of hyperlink in Pentaho Report Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474323/use-of-hyperlink-in-pentaho-report-designer)

And incorrectly use the [pentaho-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-visual-studio) tag, which references an unrelated suite of Pentaho products:

[Pentaho Report Designer with Text Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349906/pentaho-report-designer-with-text-output)

Adding a Pentaho Report Designer tag would enable us to not only correctly categorize a few hundred posts, it would de-clutter a few dozen commonly abused tags currently used to compensate.

Comment: I'm very unfamiliar with Pentaho (despite answering a question in the tag yesterday). Is the Report Designer programming related? It seems mostly GUI.

Comment: @Laurel, that's a good question. It's not directly programming related in that the primary interface is a GUI, but proper use of it requires the use of multiple programming languages (primarily SQL, but also HTML, RTF, and others). Questions related to Pentaho Report Designer asked on this site should only be programming in nature, obviously, but we have plenty of tags for applications that aren't directly programming related (e.g. `adobe-illustrator`), but they exist for the programming-related questions about them.

Comment: There are a bunch of off-topic questions that get asked in tags like Adobe Illustrator, but that's probably inevitable. A tag would at least help unify things, but I have another question first. Is [Pentaho-Reporting](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/Pentaho+Reporting+-+User+Guide+for+Report+Designer) the same thing? (And would it be a better name?)

Comment: I agree that it's likely to be abused, but it seems to be the best option available. At the very least it consolidates multiple types of abuse into one category for simplified flagging.

Comment: And yes, Pentaho-Reporting is the same thing, but it's a rarely--if ever--used term. Technically Pentaho-Reporting refers to the entire suite, while Report Designer is the design tool itself. While Reporting would be a more correct term, I think that it's so unused of a term that people wouldn't even know to look for it. Everyone I know in the industry uses the term Report Designer to mean Reporting. Similar to how "SQL Server" is used to refer to "Microsoft SQL Server". Maybe we need a tag and a synonym.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just created [pentaho-report-designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pentaho-report-designer). I'm not an expert (obviously), so I suggest that you create the tag wiki/excerpt.

I don't have enough reputation in the tag to create a synonym. Hopefully the tag I just made will be obvious enough on its own.

If you're going to be retagging things, I suggest that you fix the grammatical mistakes. You seem to have excellent English skills, and many of these questions (judging from what you linked) are grammatical messes. I will add it to the linked questions, since I cleaned up the grammar earlier.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a very basic excerpt summary for the time being and will hopefully expand in the future. I've begun working through old posts needing the tag, and I will take your suggestion to edit as I go.